# How to convert type="datetime-local" to H:i:s

Tags: javascript

```
<input name="expire_date" class="form-control" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Expiry Date">
```

I have to send the expire date to the php backend which will only accept time in H:i:s format.
So how to convert it in that format.
Is it better to convert it in frontend or change the format in backend.

I need to modify the below to code to include seconds 00 and remove the T and convert it to space because the date time local format is 2017-06-01T08:30 so it should be 2017-06-01 08:30:00

```css
function ConvertTimeformat(format, str) {
    var time = $("#starttime").val();
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if (AMPM == "PM" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "AM" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    alert(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
}

$("#btnConvert").on("click", function () {
    ConvertTimeformat("24", $("#txttime").val());
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="starttime" value="10:00 PM" />
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" value="Convert to 24 Hours" />
```

Comment: You only really have control over the backend, hence... Do it there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your format need add 0 before year. but this code should do

```
function ConvertTimeformat(format, str) {
    var time = $("#starttime").val();
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if (AMPM == "PM" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "AM" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
    var now = new Date();
    var year = now.getYear()+ 1900;
    var month = ('0' + now.getMonth().toString()).substr(-2);
    var day = ('0' + now.getDay().toString()).substr(-2);
    var finalDate = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${sHours}:${sMinutes}:00`;
  console.log(finalDate);
}
```

Comment: its a typo 2017